# Parsing key / value subparameters

Tags: antlr4

I'm a bit clueless as to how I can parse (more or less) "free form" parameter lists, suppose the syntax allows for

```
PARM=(VAL1, 'VAL2', VAL3, KEY4=VAL4, KEY5=VAL5(XYZ), PARM=ABC, SOMETHING=ELSE)
```

I have managed to basically parse combos of positional and key/value parameters, but as soon as I hit a lexer token like PARM= the parser bails out with a "mismatched input", and I can't specifically allow for or expect anything because these parameters passed to a function are completely arbitrary.

So I'd think I'll need to switch to a specific lexer mode but right now I can't see how I would properly switch back to "normal" mode, the delimiters are PARM=( on the left and the closing ) on the right, but as the "data" itself can contain (pairs of) brackets how would I identify the correct closing paren so I don't prematurely end the lexer mode?

TIA - Alex

Edit 1:

Minimal grammar showing the issue with keywords being used where they shouldn't, as this is part of a complex grammar I can't change the order of tokens to put ID in front of everything else, for example, as it would catch too much. So I don't see how this can work short of breaking out into a different lexer mode.

```
lexer grammar ParmLexer;

  SPACE     :   [ \t\r\n]+    -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
  COMMA     :   ',' ;
  EQUALS    :   '=' ;
  LPAREN    :   '(' ;
  RPAREN    :   ')' ;

  PARM      :   'PARM=' ;

  ID        :   ID_LITERAL ;
  fragment ID_LITERAL   :   [A-Za-z]+ ;
```

.

```
parser grammar ParmParser;

options { tokenVocab=ParmLexer; }

parms :     PARM LPAREN parm+ RPAREN    ;
parm :      (pkey=ID EQUALS)? pval=ID COMMA?    ;
```

Input:

```
PARM=( TEST, KEY=VAL, PARM=X)
```

Results in

```
line 1:22 extraneous input 'PARM=' expecting {')', ID}
```

Comment: please add your grammar (or better yet, a minimal grammar demonstrating your issue).  There's really not enough here to go on.  Off hand, there's no reason you'd need to use parser modes to handle the `PARM=` stuff, but there's not enough detail to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I'd think I'll need to switch to a specific lexer mode but right now I can't see how I would properly switch back to "normal" mode

Instead of switching to modes (with `-> mode(...)`), you can push your "special" mode on a stack (with `-> pushMode(...)`) and then when encountering a `)` you pop a mode from the stack. That way, you can have multiple nested lists `(..(..(..).)..)`. A quick demo:

```
lexer grammar ParmLexer;

SPACE  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
EQUALS : '=' ;
LPAREN : '(' -> pushMode(InList);
PARM   : 'PARM';
ID     : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]*;

mode InList;

 LST_LPAREN : '(' -> type(LPAREN), pushMode(InList);
 RPAREN     : ')' -> popMode;
 COMMA      : ',';
 LST_EQUALS : '=' -> type(EQUALS);
 STRING     : '\'' ~['\r\n]* '\'';
 LST_ID     : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]* -> type(ID);
 LST_SPACE  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

and:

```
parser grammar ParmParser;

options { tokenVocab=ParmLexer; }

parse
 : PARM EQUALS list EOF
 ;

list
 : LPAREN ( value ( COMMA value )* )? RPAREN
 ;

value
 : ID
 | STRING
 | key_value
 | ID list
 ;

key_value
 : ID EQUALS value
 ;
```

which will parse your example input `PARM=(VAL1, 'VAL2', VAL3, KEY4=VAL4, KEY5=VAL5(XYZ), PARM=ABC, SOMETHING=ELSE)` like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bart, brilliant as always !

Shame on me for not seeing it myself, it's just so obvious :-(

Comment: Sorry, too happy too soon, trying to fit this into my larger grammar I found this doesn't really solve it. I want it to kick in for PARM=() only, but not for all occasions of parenthesized stuff, only in this very special case I want the parser to be agnostic of what's inside the parens. When I mode() or pushMode() on PARM=( or just PARM= instead of the left paren in general and then again on all contained left and right parens thereafter this falls apart because the mode stack is off by one.

Comment: @Alex.W could you create a new question with at least 1 example that demonstrate the current shortcomings?

Comment: Done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72439942/parsing-an-arbitrary-parenthesized-value-key-value-list)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a rule (alternative) that recognizes a `PARM` token in your `parm` rule.

Bart has provided an answer using Lexer modes (and assuming that `LPAREN` and `RPAREN` always control those modes), but you can also just set up a parser rule that matches all of your keywords:

```
lexer grammar ParmLexer
    ;

SPACE:  [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
COMMA:  ',';
EQUALS: '=';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';

PARM: 'PARM';
KW1:  'KW1';
KW2:  'KW2';

ID:                  ID_LITERAL;
fragment ID_LITERAL: [A-Za-z]+;
```

```
parser grammar ParmParser
    ;

options {
    tokenVocab = ParmLexer;
}

parms: PARM EQUALS LPAREN parm (COMMA parm)* RPAREN;
parm:  ((pkey = ID | kwid = kw) EQUALS)? pval = ID;
kw:    PARM | KW1 | KW2;
```

input

```
"PARM=( TEST, KEY=VAL, KW2=v2, PARM=X)"
```

yields:

```
(parms PARM = ( (parm TEST) , (parm KEY = VAL) , (parm (kw KW2) = v) , (parm (kw PARM) = X) ))
```

Comment: As I tried to explain, these parms can be ANYTHING and thus I can NOT add explicit rules for every known token.

This was just an example to highlight why I think this doesn't work without switching to a lexical mode stripping all the "known keywords" and allow me to parse ANY combo of value | key=value.

And "value" can contain parentheses as well thus I am uncertain about how to properly switch back to default mode.

Comment: everything other than "PARM=" is covered by the first alternative.  Maybe post an example of what doesn't work??

Comment: I've revised the answer to cover a method that allows you to deal with keywords, without going using lexical modes.