# Parsing an arbitrary, parenthesized value / key=value list

Tags: antlr4

This is a follow up to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72410234/parsing-key-value-subparameters)

I need to parse a free-form value + key/value list wrapped in parentheses, but only for specific tokens, not all parenthesized elements in general.

Sample input

```
FUNC=(KEY1=VAL1, KEY2=VAL2)
PARM=(VAL1, 'VAL2', VAL3, KEY4=VAL4, KEY5=VAL5(XYZ), PARM=ABC, SOMETHING=ELSE)
```

Where FUNC= requires specific parameters / keys whereas PARM= is totally free-form

Approximation grammar

```
lexer grammar ParmLexer;

EOL: ( [ ]* ('\r' | '\n' | '\r\n') );
SPACE  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
EQUALS : '=' ;
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
COMMA  : ',';
PARM   : 'PARM='  -> mode(ListMode);
FUNC   : 'FUNC=' ;
KEY1   : 'KEY1' ;
KEY2   : 'KEY2' ;
ID     : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]*;

mode ListMode;

LST_LPAREN : '(' -> pushMode(ListMode);
LST_RPAREN : ')' -> popMode;
LST_EQUALS : '=' -> type(EQUALS);
LST_COMMA  : ',' -> type(COMMA);
STRING     : '\'' ~['\r\n]* '\'';
List_ID   :   ~[,=]+ ;
LST_SPACE  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

.

```
parser grammar ParmParser;

options { tokenVocab=ParmLexer; }

root : parse ( EOL+ parse)* EOL* EOF ;

parse
 : parse_func
 | parse_parm
;

parse_func
 : FUNC LPAREN KEY1 EQUALS ID COMMA KEY2 EQUALS ID RPAREN
;

parse_parm
 : PARM parmlist EOF
;

parmlist :
 LST_LPAREN list LST_RPAREN
;

list
 : LST_LPAREN* ( value ( COMMA value )* )? LST_RPAREN*
;

value
 : pval=List_ID
 | STRING
 | key_value
 | ID list
;

key_value
 : pkey=List_ID EQUALS pval=List_ID
;
```

This basically parses both FUNC= and PARM= correctly BUT appears to have an issue with the surrounding parens around the PARM= list

[image: ParseTree]

Note: this doesn't handle the recursive parsing of parenthesized elements as per Bart's grammer in the original question, I don't really need it here and it would be a bonus, but for the sake of completeness, when I change the lexer token to

```
List_ID   :   ~[(),=]+ ;
```

this is what happens

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

Lexer:

```
lexer grammar ParmLexer;

EOL: ( [ ]* ('\r' | '\n' | '\r\n') );
SPACE  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
EQUALS : '=' ;
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
COMMA  : ',';
PARM   : 'PARM=(' -> pushMode(ListMode);
FUNC   : 'FUNC=' ;
KEY1   : 'KEY1' ;
KEY2   : 'KEY2' ;
ID     : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]*;

mode ListMode;

LST_LPAREN : '(' -> pushMode(ListMode);
LST_RPAREN : ')' -> popMode;
LST_EQUALS : '=' -> type(EQUALS);
LST_COMMA  : ',' -> type(COMMA);
STRING     : '\'' ~['\r\n]* '\'';
List_ID    : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]*;
LST_SPACE  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

parser:

```
parser grammar ParmParser;

options { tokenVocab=ParmLexer; }

root
 : parse ( EOL+ parse )* EOL* EOF
 ;

parse
 : parse_func
 | parse_parm
 ;

parse_func
 : FUNC LPAREN KEY1 EQUALS ID COMMA KEY2 EQUALS ID RPAREN
 ;

parse_parm
 : PARM parm_list
 ;

parm_list
 : ( value ( COMMA value )* )? LST_RPAREN
 ;

value
 : id LST_LPAREN parm_list
 | id
 | key_value
 | STRING
 ;

key_value
 : pkey=id EQUALS pval=value
 ;

id
 : ID
 | List_ID
 ;
```

resulting in:

[image]

And `FUNC=` after `PARM=` will also parse correctly:

[image]

Btw, is [this](https://github.com/cschneid-the-elder/mapa/tree/master/jcl) not something similar as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for this, however, there is an issue when PARM=() isn't the last input line, when you put the FUNC= line after the PARM= line you get
line 1:79 mismatched input '\nFUNC' expecting {<EOF>, EOL}

Comment: @Alex.W ah, yes, the modes get mixed up. In that case, it is easiest to let `'('` be part of the `PARM` token and not use `-> mode(...)`, but `-> pushMode(...)`: `PARM   : 'PARM=(' -> pushMode(ListMode);`. That way the popping of modes will be correct. I've updated my answer.